# Combining columns in macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I know this topic is covered in a lot of different ways. I only just started looking at vba and macro's today but I haven't been able to find or adjust any of the solutions I found.

I am pulling 4 columns of data in 4 different excel files with about 500 columns and 2-4k rows of data in each file.

I figured out how to compile the columns of interest into a single excel file with the following (inelegant) solution (see below).

I'm hoping someone can either point me towards how to take those 16 columns and change them into 4 columns (or if anyone can explain how to get the data into 4 columns in the first place that would also be great).

Thank you!

```
Sub Macro2()

' Macro2 Macro


    Workbooks.Open Filename:="[path]"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="[path]"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="[path]"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="[path]"

    Workbooks("Stroop_Distressing_A_out.csv").activate
        Sheets("Stroop_Distressing_A_out.csv").select
            Range("GL:GL, HP:HP, IJ:IJ, IS:IS").copy
    Workbooks("Merge Excel Data Macro1.xlsm").activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").select
            Range("A:D").select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

    Workbooks("Stroop_Distressing_B_out.csv").Activate
    Sheets("Stroop_Distressing_B_out.csv").Select
            Range("GL:GL, HP:HP, IK:IK, IT:IT").Copy
    Workbooks("Merge Excel Data Macro1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
              Range("E:H").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Workbooks("Stroop_Distressing_C_out.csv").activate
        Sheets("Stroop_Distressing_C_out.csv").select
            Range("DV:DV, EZ:EZ, FU:FU, GD:GD").copy
    Workbooks("Merge Excel Data Macro1.xlsm").activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").select     
    Workbooks("Merge Excel Data Macro1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
              Range("I:L").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Workbooks("Stroop_Distressing_D_out.csv").activate
        Sheets("Stroop_Distressing_D_out.csv").select
            Range("GL:GL, HP:HP, IK:IK, IT:IT").copy
    Workbooks("Merge Excel Data Macro1.xlsm").activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").select     
        Workbooks("Merge Excel Data Macro1.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
              Range("M:P").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that your VBA macro completed successfully, the rest of the task can be performed using the following Sub:

```
Sub AggregateColumns()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim maxRowSource As Integer
    Dim maxRowTarget As Integer

    Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = Sheets("Sheet2")

    maxRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    maxRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    wsSource.Range("A1:D" & maxRowSource).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A1")

    maxRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    maxRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    wsSource.Range("E1:H" & maxRowSource).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A" & maxRowTarget + 1)

    maxRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    maxRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    wsSource.Range("I1:L" & maxRowSource).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A" & maxRowTarget + 1)

    maxRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    maxRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    wsSource.Range("M1:P" & maxRowSource).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A" & maxRowTarget + 1)

End Sub
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,